# How can I use Perl's WWW::Mechanize to check if a web page has been updated?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm using WWW::Mechanize to retrieve a webpage. I need to check if the page has been updated and retreive information from it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`mirror` method](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#%24ua-%3Emirror%28%20%24url%2C%20%24filename%20%29). This works fine for `GET` requests, see the `method` attribute of the `form` element which you are submitting. Just take note of the [URI](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize#%24mech-%3Euri%28%29) where you arrived, use it to repeatedly call `mirror`. Then there is no need to fill and submit the form anymore.

In the case of `POST`, you are not able to leverage any assistance from the HTTProtocol (conditional requests, ETags and other cacheability features). You have to manually write out fetched results to files, then [compare](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Compare.html) them.

Comment: Here's my problem..the page I want to mirror is obtained through submit_form. How do I mirror that?

Comment: You should have mentioned this important part in the question. I added some more text to my answer to deal with the form complication.